# why do i get type error for bind in reactjs

Tags: c#, reactjs

I get this error when executing my react code

*react-dom.development.js:11365 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')*

```
this.fetchQuestionCapabilities = this.fetchQuestionCapabilities.bind(this)
```

Comment: You need to show more code of your project. How is fetchQuestionCapabilities implemented and is it inside your class?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.